# What hinders SN2 more: geminal alkyl group or alkyl group on the aromatic ring?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, nucleophilic-substitution

> Which among these two (1-chloro-1-phenyl-ethane and 2-(chloromethyl)-1,3-dimethylbenzene) is more reactive towards S<sub>N</sub>2?
>
> [image]

I strongly believe that it should be Y because of lesser hindrance *on the electrophilic carbon*.

However, the answer key of my exercise book states that X > Y. What's the reason behind that?

Comment: Which book is this? Could you please mention the source? Thanks!

Comment: @schrodinger_16 it's himanshu pandey's advanced problems in organic chemistry for JEE

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is X because the 2 methyl groups on the Y are bulky enough to cause steric hindrance. Surprisingly, from what I have seen, if you only had one methyl group on Y, the SN2 reaction would proceed.

Comment: Got a reference for that?

Comment: There's plenty of examples of SN2 on dimethyl substrates like Y. Rates are certainly going to be slower, but it's not too difficult of a substrate compared to others.

Comment: Needs a citation. In the reactive conformation, Cl–C–Nu should be parallel to the ring. In the absence of some data I'm skeptical as to how much steric hindrance those methyl groups actually produce. I would be happy to be convinced otherwise, of course.